# Multistore setup help

Tags: multistore

hope you can help, bit of a Magento newbie- I'm a bit confused with the websites/stores/storeviews setup.  What's the best way to configure this  :

- 4 retail stores (will grow to >10 in next 6 months)
- each store has a different domain
- all selling the same products at same price
- using one payment gateway (payments to be manually reconciled every week)
- each store has own logo, branding etc (header and footer)
- each store has different about us, contact us, map

Thanks!

Comment: what about stock management]

Comment: Hi - good question - no, stock management isn't required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can manage all the thing by using store view.

But only issue with `Shopping Cart and Catalog rules`.Both are setup basic of website scope. If you using this store view then for 4 retail stores same, if a shopping cart or catalogue rules apply then it wil effect on all 4 retail store.

If want to  resolved the shopping Cart and Catalogues then you need to create a website ,a store and a store view for each  retail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We want the products to be supplied from the store the buyer chooses (so for example at checkout they are asked which store they want to use), so the order gets directed to that store for them to ship. Is that possible using the Store View as above?  And can we have a pick up from store option?

Comment: buyer cannnot choose the store at checkout... You can  ceate dropdown at checkout and using  this redirect to another store  url with carry current cart items

Comment: I thought adding product to a cart created a sessionID  that couldn't be carried over to another URL?

Comment: yes,using transfer session ,cart item can be transfer to another store